# R package: underscores added to RcppExports.R when building

Tags: r, rstudio, r-package

I work from different computers on the same R package with Rstudio, but for some reason, whenever I build the package, some of the computers will modify the `RcppExports.R` and `RcppExports.cpp` files by adding underscore in front of some functions. For example, this can be found when looking at the dif between the files before and after compiling the package (first line is before, second is after):

```
    .Call('PkgName_FunctionName', PACKAGE = 'PkgName', arguments)
    .Call('_PkgName_FunctionName', PACKAGE = 'PkgName', arguments)
```

This bothers me because git sees this as a change.

My questions are:

- Why is the underscore included?
- What can I do to have compiling the package not modify any of the files?

Comment: Are you using different versions of R/packages on the different machines? It's much easier to help when you provide some sort of [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) or enough information to recreate the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have the same (current) versions of Rcpp on both machines.  Then the `RcppExports.{R,cpp}` files will be identical.

The change was a requirement from R upstream (around R 3.4.0) and we needed to adjust.

Also note that you probably want `registration=TRUE` in your `NAMESPACE` file in which case the form becomes

```
.Call(`_PkgName_FunctionName`, arguments)
```

Comment: Just to make sure, the correct (most recent version) does include the underscore, right?

Comment: Yes, it does as you can by perusing recent package source.  The change was made last spring.