# R package fails to build after updating Rcpp

Tags: rcpp, r-package

I was trying to fix an issue regarding the insertion of underscore in my RcppExports files in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48067213/r-package-underscores-added-to-rcppexports-r-when-building) question. I found out that my R version was up to date but I was using an old Rcpp version.

After updating Rcpp, I'm unable to build and load the package, here is the log:

```
==> R CMD INSTALL --no-multiarch --with-keep.source GibbsRF

* installing to library ‘/home/victor/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4’
* installing *source* package ‘GibbsRF’ ...
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
** libs
installing to /home/victor/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/GibbsRF/libs
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded

 *** caught segfault ***
address (nil), cause 'unknown'
An irrecoverable exception occurred. R is aborting now ...
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/home/victor/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/GibbsRF’

Exited with status 1.
```

My R version is 3.4.2. It was working fine under Rcpp 0.12.11, but doesn't work on 0.12.14 and I'm unable to track where the problem is because the error message seems just too vague for me. How can I track what is going wrong? Is there a way I can get a less vague error message?

Comment: The general rule is to rebuild a dependent package if it is in trouble after one of the package it depends upon has changed.

Answer (score 1):

I was also having trouble loading an Rcpp package after updating to Rcpp 0.12.15 (R 3.3.1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu). Similarly I was getting a segfault when the installer attempted to load.

It seems to have been remedied by restarting from the "Rcpp.package.skeleton" with the new version of Rcpp, and copying over the code from src and R directories.

Interested to know if others have found a more elegant solution.